# Check whether the last three flips were all heads or all tails in Python

Tags: python

So I have a challenge, in which I have to create a programme that simulates a coin flip, by generating a random number corresponding to either heads or tails. When three simultaneous 'H' (heads) or 'T' (tails) are outputted my programme should stop. I have tried to get this to work, here is my code so far:

```
import random
active=True
list1 = []
b = 0
while active:
    l=random.randint(0,1)
    b += 1
    i='a'
    if l == 0:
        i = 'H'
    else:
        i = 'T'
    list1.append(i)

    if list1[:-3] is ['H','H','H']:
        active = False
    elif list1[:-3] is ['T','T','T']:
        active = False
    else:
        active = True
    print(list1),
```

It seems that the only thing not working is the part that checks for 3 corresponding heads or tails, does anybody know how I may code this part correctly?

Comment: list1[-3:] is what you want.

Comment: Also, use `==` for the comparison instead of `is`.

Comment: Implementing both above comments, indeed, work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

The problem, as was mentioned in the comments above, is that `list1[:-3]` should be `list1[-3:]` (getting the last three elements of the list, instead of everything *up to* the last three elements) and comparisons should be done with `==` instead of `is`. The adjusted program would be:

```
import random
active=True
list1 = []
b = 0
while active:
    l=random.randint(0,1)
    b += 1
    i='a'
    if l == 0:
        i = 'H'
    else:
        i = 'T'
    list1.append(i)

    if list1[-3:] == ['H','H','H']:
        active = False
    elif list1[-3:] == ['T','T','T']:
        active = False
    else:
        active = True
    print(list1)
```

However, I think it might also be useful to see a condensed approach at writing the same program:

```
import random

flips = []
while flips[-3:] not in (['H'] * 3, ['T'] * 3):
    flips.append(random.choice('HT'))
    print(flips)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by tracking a running list of flips. If the new flip is the same as the previous, append it to the list. Else, if the new flip is not the same as the previous, clear the list and append the new flip. Once the length reaches 3, break from the while loop:

```
import random

flipping = True
flips = []
flip_status = {0: "H", 1: "T"}
current_flip = None

while flipping:
    current_flip = flip_status[random.randint(0,1)]
    print current_flip

    if len(flips) == 0:
        flips.append(current_flip)

    else:
        if current_flip == flips[-1]:
            flips.append(current_flip)
            if len(flips) == 3:
                break
        else:
            flips = []
            flips.append(current_flip)

print "Flips: " + str(flips)
```

Here's a sample run:

```
T
T
H
T
T
H
T
H
H
T
T
T
Flips: ['T', 'T', 'T']
```